# Regex - parsing string

Tags: java, regex

Say i have a file which contains lines as follows:

```
Hayden
y
```

Suppose i want to manipulate the line which only contains "y" and not the one with Hayden, how would i do this?

So i read in the file and parse it line by line. I want to say if the line contains letters before or after "y" then it's not the line i'm looking for.

I thought i could do the following:

```
String value = "y"; 
if(strLine.matches("[a-zA-Z]" + value + "[a-zA-Z]"))
{
      don't manipulate line here
}
else
{
   manipulate string here
}
```

However, this gets "Hayden" as well as "y"

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

sorry, i should have been more clear, what if i don't mind if there are spaces or symbols in front? or behind? it's specifically the letters that i need to watch out for. For instance, i can't have yh but i can have y=... sorry again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for

```
String[] lines={"Hayden","y"," y*","y=","y+"," +y..."};
for (String s:lines)
    System.out.println(s+"->"+s.matches("\\W*y\\W*"));
```

output:

```
Hayden->false
y->true
 y*->true
y=->true
y+->true
 +y...->true
```

Comment: hmm but what about having something like y= or y+ or +y... i think this would fail in that case... but these lines are ok for me. it's just if there is a letter directly beside y - on either side, that i want to avoid..

Comment: thanks :) this actually worked. pretty cool stuff man. Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

You can use negative [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
if (strLine.matches("^.*(?<![a-zA-Z])y(?![a-zA-Z]).*$")) { 
    // manipulate string here
}
```

The anchors are optional but included anyway for clarity.

Comment: this is probably the easiest way to show if the line only contains y (and you can also use "equalsIgnoreCase()"

Comment: sorry, i should have been more clear, what if i don't mind if there are symbols? or spaces in front?

Comment: this almost works... but for some reason it's not catching y= y+y... hwo would i get around this? as i said, i don't mind there being symbols or spaces... just can't have letters right beside it.. thanks for the response btw

Comment: @MarkByers sorry, again.. i should have been more clear, i mean right next to "y" there shouldn't be any letters, but any symbol is ok

Comment: @BlueMonster: When you say any letter, do you really mean *any* letter? Because in your question you write A-Z but there are letters such as Ø that aren't included in A-Z.

Comment: @BlueMonster: Also do you want match a line like `y=Hayden`?

Comment: @MarkByers i mean letters a-z caps or not caps. the line y=Hayden is fine, but yHayden is not the line i'd be looking for

Comment: OK, but in your question you said that if a line contains a y preceded or followed by another letter, then you don't want it to match. If that part of the question is to be understood literally then it would imply that `y=Hayden` shouldn't match. So I think that part of your question is misleading. However I think my answer is what you want.

Comment: @MarkByers your answer is the closest i've seen so far! thank you.. unfortunately it fails at these lines: y = 123123123 (counts this line as one i shouldn't manipulate); y = y+y(counts this line as one i shouldn't manipulate); my_sqrt_x = "something"(counts this line as one i should manipulate);  any ideas why? every other case seems to work fine

Comment: @BlueMonster: I put an example online: http://ideone.com/viCQM It seems to work as expected for all the examples you've given. Are you sure that you're using the latest version of my answer and that you have copied and pasted it correctly?

Comment: +1 for all the help, thanks @MarkByers. Pshemos answer seems to work for me. I'm not too sure why your answer doesn't... perhaps i'm doing something weird just before, i doin't know :S but thanks again!

Comment: @BlueMonster: Strange, because when I run his code it fails to match on every single one of the examples you gave. See it for yourself here: http://ideone.com/3Bljs. So I think either you are doing something very wrong or else I'm totally misunderstanding your requirements. But if you're happy with the answer you got, and you don't want further help, then that's completely fine by me! I'm happy that you got the answer you were looking for.

Comment: hmm, you're right, i see. I think i'll have to change something in my code, your code definitely appears to be working

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
strLine.matches("^y$")
```

To ignore symbols, i.e. non-alphanumeric characters, use:

```
strLine.matches("^\\W*y\\W*$")
```

Comment: sorry, i should have been more clear, what if i don't mind if there are spaces or symbols in front? or behind? it's specifically the letters that i need to watch out for. For instance, i can't have yh but i can have y=... sorry again

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use regex, you need to be a bit more specific:

- `y` matches a `y` anywhere in the line.
- `^y$` matches a `y` that is right before the end of the string (the dollar sign) and right after the beginning of the string (the caret). This lets you match the line that is *equal* to `y`.

Answer (score 0):

Extending the equals approach: Just remove all the character you don't mind, and then check for equality with `"y"`:

```
if (strLine.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "").equals("y")) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: i can't remove the letters i don't want... they must stay there... i just have to work around them... because i don't want to manipulate those lines...

Comment: replace() does not manipulate anything, it returns a new string. The condition is to read "if I were to take out everything that is not a-Z and the rest then is just a "y", do..."

Comment: but i don't want to do anything with the line that contains other letters.... only if the line contains the letter i'm looking for and symbols or spaces... in such a case, i would like to manipulate the string. However, if i remove everything and then check if there is a "y" how do i determine that this is or is not a line containing just the letter i'm looking for and symbols (if any) - although there does not necessarily have to be any symbols...